# JBoss Fuse 6.3 - camel-jetty proxy change url

Tags: proxy, jboss, apache-camel, jetty

I have a problem with camel jetty. I use original camelContext from JBoss Fuse 6.2.1 in new JBoss Fuse 6.3. Integration Project.

Requested from url (e.g. esb.mydomain.com/test) was redirected to target url (e.g. localhost:8080/myservice) and url in web browser was kept  (esb.mydomain.com/test) in 6.2.1 version.

But when I try the same in JBoss Fuse 6.3. redirection is done but url is changed (localhost:8080/myservice).

There is camel context:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd                            http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
<camelContext id="_context1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="TestRoute">
        <from id="_from1" uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0/test?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
        <to id="_to1" uri="jetty:http://localhost:8080/myservice?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Do you have any idea where can be problem?

**UPDATED**

I tried to change route again, again and again :) and I found out following strange behavior

This route redirect to google and add url parameters from route: 
google.com?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route customId="true" id="httpBridge">
        <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0/test?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
        <to uri="jetty:https://google.com?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false" customId="true" id="to2"/>
    </route>
</routes>
```

And this works as proxy (bridge). without redirect. Google shows 404 of course because http://google.cz/x doesn't exist. But url in browser is no changed (jboss-fuse-6308331.cloudapp.net/test)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route customId="true" id="httpBridge">
        <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0/test?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
        <to uri="jetty:https://google.com/x?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false" customId="true" id="to2"/>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Only one difference is letter "x" in the end of "to google" uri. For example letter "a" redirect to google as previous example :(

Comment: Use the Red Hat customer portal to get developer/production support/help with JBoss Fuse

Comment: Thank you. It's done but no answers :(    https://developer.jboss.org/thread/273976

Comment: The customer portal is for customers so you will get help using that. The other is the public forum which is not so fast to help